# Component not re-rendering after onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've checked the previous answer on different topics about re-rendering but couldn't find a proper way to fix this.
I am trying to re-render a component after the onChange event is fired on the select box.

I have a userlist with 5 users and I separated them into genders array.
So I have a males array and a females array. I am trying to show the selected gender user list after the onChange event.

I tried to use the 'key' attr in component but it didn't work.

here is my UserList container:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import List from '../components/List.jsx'

class UserList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
     }

    renderUser = (toMap) => {
        console.log(toMap);
    return (
            <List key = {toMap.length} users = {toMap}/>
        );
  }

    renderSelect = () => {
    return (
            <select id="gender" onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="select">Select a gender</option>
        <option value="males">Males</option>
        <option value="females">Females</option>
      </select>
        );
  }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        const {userList,males,females} = this.props;
        const gender = e.target.value;

        if(gender == 'males'){
            return this.renderUser(males);
        }else if(gender == 'females'){
            return this.renderUser(females);
        }
        return this.renderUser(userList);
    }

  render() {
        const {isLoading,error,userList} = this.props;

         return (
             <div>
                 {this.renderSelect()}
           <ul>
                    {this.renderUser(userList)}
           </ul>
                </div>
     );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserList);
```

here is my List Component:

```
import React from 'react';

const List = ({users}) => (
    <ul>
        {users.map( (user,index) => (
          <li key = {index} >{user.email}</li>
        ))}
    </ul>
);

export default List;
```

the props (users) are passing correctly when I check the console in handleChange but can't quite a visual result.

Comment: You should store your selection in `state`. Your components will rerender after state changes.

Comment: Hi Ekin, could you solve this issue ?

Comment: hi @sebastienbarbier yes I updated the state.

Comment: Awesome, please feel free to mark your question as answered when you have a moment :). Have a great day.

Comment: I am so sorry marked as accepted now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## State and Lifecycle

You should use [state / setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) as a way to **trigger a rendering on react**.

> **setState()** enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state.

Main idea here is to store **gender value** in state, as we want to render when this value is changed

1. Add a initial state on your contructor

   ```
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            gender: []
        }
    }
   ```
2. **Update onChange event**, using `setState()` with a new value. This function will notify asynchroniously react about the need to rerender. You need to refactor a bit your logic to clean you change handler with just updating state. Keep in mind setState is async, might be source of misunderstanding.

   ```
     handleChange = (e) => {
        setState({gender: e.target.value});
    }
   ```
3. **Final version** should look something like this :

   ```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
   import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

   import { connect } from 'react-redux';
   import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

   import List from '../components/List.jsx'

   class UserList extends Component {

     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { gender: null };
     }

     renderUser = (toMap) => {
       return (
           <List 
               key = {toMap.length} 
               users = {toMap.filter(user => this.state.gender ? user.gender === this.state.gender : true)}/>
         );
     }

     renderSelect = () => {
       return (
         <select id="gender" onChange={this.handleChange}>
           <option value="select">Select a gender</option>
           <option value="males">Males</option>
           <option value="females">Females</option>
         </select>
       );
     }

     handleChange = (e) => {
       this.setState({ gender: e.target.value})
     }

     render() {
       const {isLoading,error,userList} = this.props;

       return (
         <div>
           { this.renderSelect() }
           <ul>
             { this.renderUser(userList) }
           </ul>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
   ```

   `renderUser()` will perform a `filter` based on selected gender. No need to store males and females as performance should be fine for most case.

Comment: You need to move your setstate below the const otherwise userList will be undefined. Also this  seems still like a messy  way to do things.

Comment: Sorry, first suggestion was quiet bad . Latest one suggest storing gender on state and filter userList on change to have the expected result

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of your code : https://codesandbox.io/s/new-wkgu6

you are not setting state anywhere because of which component is not rendering again

> **setState()** will always lead to a re-render unless
>   shouldComponentUpdate() returns false.

More information on setState api can be found here

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate