# React Initiating component re-render after onChange event received data from Paste (ctrl+v)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to initiate an API request upon paste of a URL into an input field and then show the result on the page.

According to documentation and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507156/component-not-re-rendering-after-onchange-event) link on SOF, setState is the way to initiate re-render, I know and it seems I did it the right way myself, but something is off, I get the url state only when I do onChange again, React doesn't seem to show me my pasted data anywhere in any of the available lifecycle events.

Using create-react-app:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const UserInput = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>Enter URL:</label>
      <input onChange={props.handleChange} type="text" value={props.value} />
    </div>
  );
};

class Fetch extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      url: null,
      userData: null,
      fetching: false,
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch(this.state.url)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ userData: json }))
      .error(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.render();
  }
}

const UserProfile = ({ name, gender }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hey {name}, you are {gender}!
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      url: null
    };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      url: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UserInput
          value={this.state.url}
          handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
        <Fetch url={this.state.url} render={data => <UserProfile />} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

If you paste any URL in the field, you won't have it in state, so when fetchData is triggered its

> this.state.url

is actually still null.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Fetch component and App component are using two separate copies of the `url` state which causes the issue, you have to use the `url` you pass as prop to the `Fetch` component instead.

```
class Fetch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // url: null, remove this
      userData: null,
      fetching: false,
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch(this.props.url) // update here
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ userData: json }))
      .error(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.render(userData); // the render prop is a function in your case that expects data
  }
}
```

update the below line too so that the UserProfile gets the data that has been obtained from API. I am not sure about the keys

```
<Fetch url={this.state.url} render={data => <UserProfile name={data.name} gender={data.gender}/>} />
```